# Transferring Paypal money to sons friend

Tags: currency, money-laundering, money-service

I said my son is in prison and his friend. My sons friend has a girlfriend that sends money alot to him and it has to be sent through an approved account so she sends it to me. And the friend has a friend that sent money to me once cause he dont hav a paypal. Its not money laundering to the perosn who said that. I know what money laundering is. Why u answer that? Specialy if u dont know. I am asking a similar wuestion thats on here. Im not helping anyone break the law. I was very vague in my question. And to the person that said about the cell phones. I said nothing about cell phone in jails. I said cell phones but not in jail. And i dont really see anything wrong if someone asked to use my paypal twice to get money. I sont think twice is money laundering. Come on now. Anyhow i shouldnt of put this up and it wont let me delet. The money to my payl isnt nothing big. It was just one time and my sons account is mostly his girlfriend and small amounts like 20 bucks. I dont think thats money laundering. I guess i should be more specific but i didnt and dont feel like writting it all and i can barely see what im typing on here. I just will tell him not anymore to avoid any questions like this . I can barely see this post or questions. Ty to the lady that was helpful about how i wrote it . I just want to know if its ok if someone sends money to paypal its money someone owes him and he dont hav a paypal cause he is in jail. Its not money laundering cause its not been a bunch of times. He has asked once and asked if id do it one more time. I just wanted to know if u thought it sounded true. So i told him no and he was like mom its one time its money he is owed he dont hav paypal to get the money. So what does that sound like to u

Comment: If you are asking whether something is illegal you need to tell us where you are (country, state if in the US). Also I think this question would be better posed on law.SE rather than here.

Comment: Instead of asking whether it is legal, consider asking whether you really want to be part of this scheme. X sends money to you, and you forward it to Y. So why doesn't X just send it straight to Y? If X will get in trouble for sending Y the money, it stands to reason that *you* would get in trouble for sending Y the money.

Comment: "*I know he wouldn't have me do illegal things.*"  We have less faith in your son than you do.

Comment: "*Its not money laundering cause its not been a bunch of times.*" The government doesn't see it that way.

Comment: "So what does that sound like to u".  It sounds like you don't really want our answers.

Comment: But it is for money owed. One time how would that be money laundering? Now my son said he is kicking me out his life. Smh just because i wont do it. Smh. I know what money laundering is but i know its not that. Its just someone in jail that cant collect his money cause he dont hav paypal. Which is true. They cant hav accounts or they dont hav access to it i believ him but idk. I told him thats fine if he dont wanna talk to me

Comment: "So what does that sound like to u" Mostly weird: a block of text where one can only guess what you try to communiate. A bit of structure and some more clarity really would help.

Comment: Sounds like money laundering to me...

Answer (score 8):

> But lately he has had his friend use my PayPal account. Someone will send me money and then I transfer it to where he tells me. To cash app or venmo.

That's money laundering.  Definitely illegal.

> He said it's money owed for cellphones.

People in jail aren't supposed to have cellphones.  You are helping him break the law, which means you are helping him break the law.

Comment: Also, it is probably for drugs or other contraband and not cell phones.

Comment: I wasnt specific enough in questions. Its only been money once and ask for a last time. i dont think its drugs n llaundering. And i didnt say its for cell  in jails. They have tablets. state gives them that. its difficult 4me to read on here cause its small so i dint put up everything plus i dont really know anything. son tells me the money from paypal is money the guy was owed. He doesnt even know what its 4The guy just asked him to ask me. Being in prison when someone asks u do Not me him. I wont do anything illegal. Basically i was told that he is owed money

Comment: @LisaEstrada you're letting known criminals (**at best** criminal **associates**) use your PayPal account.  You're original question was, "Fishy. Is transferring money illegal?" and you're absolute right to be fishy, because **it is illegal**.

Comment: @LisaEstrada if PayPal finds out, they'll cut off your account.

Comment: It was one time. He asked to use my paypal csuse he dont have one. He said someone owed him money. Why would that be illegal?  I mean someone could actually owe someone money. Its not like they r using my papal all the time. If it was all the time id peob think a little diffrent. Just because someone is in jail doesnt always make them a criminal. My son is actually in there because of being somewhere and not doing anything. Its hard to explain. I sont think someone owing someone money or someones girlfriend put money on books would be illegal. If it was being done all the time or daily thenya

Comment: I cant wven write what i want cause i dont hav enough space or charters. I called paypal about it already. I told him no then he said that its just one more time. He said someone owes him money and he dont hav paypal. I just wont do it but i feel bad because he said its just money he is owed and he dont hav paypal cause he is in jail. I mean they r in jail so what else could it be for. How can it be for anything else then what he says. Idk i guess since im questioning it i shouldnt  do it   i told them my paypal has a hold so i cant. Which it does so i just showed him that and he stopped askin

Comment: "How can it be for anything else then what he says."  He **might** be lying to you.  It happens on a distressingly frequent basis.

Comment: I said use paypal but i meant he sent me money once on paypal not more than once. When he asked again i was like what

Comment: Im sure it does happen but my son would never do anything to get me in trouble.

Comment: Ron im sure i sound stupid.

Comment: Reading all this makes me think. Inreally dont think its money laundering cause it was once. I think if it was all the time then ues. But u all dont know my kid. They dont hav money to launder or thise kind of connections so id never think that. Not enough money. Just one time and then his gf thats sends him money weekly.

Comment: Ok its over. He is getting someone else to do it. He is mad and says im tripping. Idk it might be nothing wrong but just in case ‍♀️

Comment: "Ron im sure i sound stupid."  You sound like a mother who loves her son very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has been addressed, but:

**Contact a lawyer**

You shouldn't trust random people on the internet with this. You feel uncomfortable, and potentially participate in crimes. You should talk to a specialist, **talk to a lawyer**.

That doesn't seem like a very complex problem, but you need a legal advice. There are [some non-profits](https://clinics.law.harvard.edu/plap/) that help with legal aid to incarcerated people and their families. You need to find one in your jurisdiction/location.